# Entity not persisting one value in Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've come up against a strange issue which I cannot seem to figure out.

I'm creating a CRM in Symfony 2 implementing Doctrine, and using an OpenCart database.

There is the ability to add an order via the CRM which persists the data given into the relevant tables, but I'm falling at the final hurdle. I'm trying to persist the order ID yet for some reason I'm getting the error:

> order_id cannot be null

This is how the entity entry is set up in the file:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
 private $orderId;
```

And I'm using this to set it:

```
$order_option->setOrderId($order_id);
```

I know for a fact that $order_id has an integer value, as I've printed it out before persisting (I even tried hard coding it into the set function) but it still ends up being null.

I am confused as to why this is happening since every other set is working, plus it's even correctly assigned the value to the `$this->orderId` variable as I tried debugging that too.

If anyone can maybe shed some light on this I would be grateful.

Comment: You say "persists the data given into the relevant tables." Is the controller persisting into multiple tables at once (cascade)? Is it perhaps trying to persist data into the table before you have setOrderId?

Comment: No, it's just a singular table, orderId is not the primary key nor is autoincremental (it can be duplicated since this table is the order totals table). Doesn't matter where in the list of sets I add this, it always skips it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

There was a protected variable called `$product` in the entity which was being joined by `order_id`, however this is never persisted or referenced. So, I just deleted it and now the order_id is persisted as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to add `@ORM\Id`

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
 private $orderId;
```

Comment: It's not the primary Id though.